# Google Plus Authentication Callback Not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, oauth, sequelize.js

I've added Google + sign in but the callback doesn't seem to be working.

***Note:*** The code was adapted from this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google

## The Scenario

1. I go to the URL: https://gym-up-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/oauth/google
2. This initiates the Google Login Process through their website
3. Login is successful + **Data is inserted into MySQL DB**
4. App then gets taken to Error Page

It seems to be failing to call the callback URL which should be:
https://gym-up-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/oauth/google/callback

I'm using the following dependencies: Express, MySQL, Sequelize, Passport

Here is my code:

**Routes:**

```
// =====================================
// GOOGLE ROUTES =======================
// =====================================
// send to google to do the authentication
// profile gets us their basic information including their name
// email gets their emails
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

// the callback after google has authenticated the user
router.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"), 
function(req,res) {
  res.render("index");
  console.log("After Passport AUTH");
});
```

**Passport JS**

```
// =========================================================================    


// GOOGLE ==================================================================
  // =========================================================================
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL
      },
      function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log("getting data from Google");
        // make the code asynchronous
        // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Google
        process.nextTick(function() {
          // try to find the user based on their google id
          console.log("profile ID :", profile.id);
          models.User.findOne({ where: { ggId: profile.id } }).then(function(
            user
          ) {
            // if (err) return done(err);
            if (user) {
              // if a user is found, log them in
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
              var data = {
                // set all of the relevant information
                ggId: profile.id,
                ggToken: token,
                ggName: profile.displayName,
                ggEmail: profile.emails[0].value // pull the first email
              };
              //save user
              models.User.create(data, {
                fields: ["ggId", "ggToken", "ggName", "ggEmail"]
              }).then(function(insertedUser) {
                console.log(
                  "User Created!" + ": " + insertedUser.get({ plain: true })
                );
                // console.log("about to run DONE to go back to ROUTE");
                // return done(null, insertedUser.get({ plain: true }));
                if (!insertedUser) {
                  console.log("failed to insert user - nothing found!");
                  return done(null, false);
                }
                if (insertedUser) {
                  console.log("about to run DONE to go back to ROUTE");
                  return done(null, insertedUser);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. But I'm not entirely sure why it works.

```
// the callback after google has authenticated the user
router.get("/google/callback", function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("google", function(err, user, info) {
    res.redirect("/profile");
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Hope this helps someone else. Took a long time to figure this one out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the callback url to the google authenticate in callback route. The tutorial you have mentioned has the successRedirect and failureRedirect routes.

For Example: add success and failure route as follows.

```
// route for success
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
});


 // route for failure
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

then add pass success and failure routes to the google authenticate

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback',
        passport.authenticate('google', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
        }));
```

Comment: I added both the routes you suggested but it still doesn't seem to work. I also tested both the routes to ensure they render too. Everything seems to authenticate find but when it comes back to my application it just errors. Any other suggestions?

Comment: All I see is: `500 (Internal Server Error)` - it doesn't seem to cause any other errors. When I run the code it executes the passport JS code and get to the  `return done(null, insertedUser);` part because I see `console.log("about to run DONE to go back to ROUTE");` is printed which I assume means it is returning back to the routes and it should then run `successRedirect` is that right? So I'm not sure why it's not rendering.